# close curl connection after telnet

Tags: curl, containers, telnet

**What I Want:**

After a successful connection, I want curl to exit successfully. I am running this command inside a container, so I want the curl command to exit successfully so that the container will too.

**Here is my example:**

```
$ curl -v telnet://google.com:443/
*   Trying 172.217.197.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.197.113) port 443 (#0)
```

**Options I have tried:**

**No Keep Alive:**

```
$ curl -v --no-keepalive telnet://google.com:443/
*   Trying 172.217.197.102...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.197.102) port 443 (#0)
```

**Connection Timeout:**

```
$ curl -v --connect-timeout 5 telnet://google.com:443/
*   Trying 172.217.197.139...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.197.139) port 443 (#0)
```

**Keep Alive Time:**

```
$ curl -v --keepalive-time 5 telnet://google.com:443/
*   Trying 172.217.197.139...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.197.139) port 443 (#0)
```

**Flag Definitions**

`--no-keepalive (Disable keepalive use on the connection)`

`--connect-timeout (SECONDS  Maximum time allowed for connection)`

`--keepalive-time (SECONDS  Wait SECONDS between keepalive probes)`

Answer (score 6):

To make curl exit immediately upon a successful telnet connection, purposely pass an unknown telnet option and test for an exit code is 48:

```
curl --telnet-option 'BOGUS=1' --connect-timeout 2 -s telnet://google.com:443 </dev/null
code=$?
if [ "$?" -eq 48 ]; then
  echo "Telnet connection was successful"
else
  echo "Telnet connection failed. Curl exit code was $code"
fi
```

We purposely passed an unknown telnet option, `BOGUS=1`, to curl's [`-t, --telnet-option`](https://www.mankier.com/1/curl#-t) option. Replace `BOGUS` with any name you want other than the three supported options of `TTYPE`, `XDISPLOC`, or `NEW_ENV`.

48 is curl's error code for *"[CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION (48)](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLEUNKNOWNOPTION) An option passed to libcurl is not recognized/known."*

This works because the telnet options are processed only after a successful connection.

### Slight variation

Purposely pass a telnet option with bad syntax, such as `BOGUS` or an empty string, and test for an exit code of 49 ([CURLE_SETOPT_OPTION_SYNTAX](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLESETOPTOPTIONSYNTAX)). We use this approach in the following function. As before, this works because curl processes the telnet options only after a successful connection.

### Formalized as a function

```bash
# Args:
# 1 - host
# 2 - port
tcp_port_is_open() {
   local code
   curl --telnet-option BOGUS --connect-timeout 2 -s telnet://"$1:$2" </dev/null
   code=$?
   case $code in
     49) return 0 ;;
     *) return "$code" ;;
   esac
}
```

### Tests

```bash
tcp_port_is_open example.com 80
echo "$?"
# 0 ✔️

tcp_port_is_open example.com 1234
echo "$?"
# 28 - Operation timeout ✔️

tcp_port_is_open nonexistent.example.com 80
echo "$?"
# 6 - Couldn't resolve host. ✔️
```

### Edit: May 27, 2022: Watch this todo item

https://curl.se/docs/todo.html#exit_immediately_upon_connection
Via: https://curl.se/mail/archive-2022-04/0027.html

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was sending "exit" to telnet and since you are not intressted in the output, redirect it

```
$ echo "exit" | curl --connect-timeout 1 -s telnet://google.com:443 > /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
$ echo "exit" | curl --connect-timeout 1 -s telnet://google.com:4433 > /dev/null
$ echo $?
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the -m/--max-time option that will set a max time  in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take.

$ curl -vm 5 telnet://google.com:443

- About to connect() to google.com port 443 (#0)
- Trying 142.251.163.113... connected
- Connected to google.com (142.251.163.113) port 443 (#0)
- Time-out
- Closing connection #0
  curl: (28) Time-out